# How can i install the right version of autossh on CentOS?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, centos

I need to know what version of centos installed and need to install autossh in centos.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

> uname -a
>
> cat /etc/redhat-release

- these will output the name of the OS with it's version number.

To install AutoSSH, follow these steps:

> http://www.jbmurphy.com/2011/04/29/autossh-on-centos/

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded source, and then

```
./configure
make
```

Then use executable that was build (or make install to get it in standard location). It's fairly simple and does not have much dependencies.